# finding eigenvalue of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

I got this problem from NET exam 2016 June. The problem will be done if the eigenvalue of this special type of matrix can be evaluated. The special type of matrix is $A$ whose $(i,j)^{\rm  th}$ element is $1/(i+j+1)$ where $i, j$ belong to $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$. Options were

a) $\dim v = n$.
b) $\dim v > n$.
c) $A$ is non negative definite.
d) $\det A > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to evaluate the determinant or know the eigenvalues of the matrix to answer the question. The dimension of $V$ is $n + 1$ with basis $f_0(x) = 1, f_1(x) = x, \dots, f_n(x) = x^n$ so $(a)$ is false and $(b)$ is true. The expression

$$ \left< f, g \right> := \int_0^1 f(x) g(x) \, dx $$

defines an inner product on $V$ and $A$ is the Gramian matrix of $(V,\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>)$ with respect to the ordered basis $(f_i)_{i=0}^{n}$. Hence, $A$ is positive definite and so both $(c)$ and $(d)$ are true (assuming that $(c)$ means semipositive-definite).

BTW, the matrix $A$ is called a [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) and you can find its determinant explicitly. However, you don't need to do it in order to solve the question.

Comment: I think it will be less complicated if we think through Hilbert Matrix...